# Can a non-significant regression model be used for prediction?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, predictive-models

I am planning to predict Y (speech recognition scores) from X (age). There is a linear relationship. Hence examined the data using linear regression. Linear regression is not significant. Can I still predict if linear regression is not significant?

---

This is the ANOVA table:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean that linear regression is not significant?

Comment: Would you please add a data scatterplot to the question?

Comment: Right, age is not predictive of speech recognition scores. The way that you would predict a speech recognition score would be by guessing the average of all observed speech recognition scores, since including age does not give additional insight.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I am sorry I am new to this community. I will try and explain here.  I did two separate regressions, one for the control group and one for the experimental group [x =age, y = speech recognition scores]. The regression is significant for the control group, but it is not significant for the experimental group. I can predict speech recognition scores for control. But can I predict for the experimental group?   Thank you

Comment: @Dave On the contrary, these results clearly show that age *in these data* does have some predictive value.  Given the assumption "there is a linear relationship," we have no right to deny it based on these data, nor can we expect that using the mean is going to work better.  Sam: please edit your question to reflect what you actually did and what you actually need to ask.

Comment: @whuber Saying that age has predictive value in this data set seems akin to getting $\bar{x}=0.001$, running a t-test with $H_0:\mu_X=0$, getting $p=0.7$, and concluding that  $\mu_X \ne 0$ just because the sample mean happened to have a tiny difference. Certainly this particular sample has a mean other than zero, but that isn't inference. Where am going awry?

Comment: @Dave You are trusting the p-value too much.  Sometimes prior knowledge deserves stronger weight than comparing a p-value to a significance threshold.  I am suggesting that we should respect that and respect the possibility that what our client "knows" (even if we doubt he's correct :-)) might be true.  Indeed, a p-value of 0.199 does not demonstrate the regression is worthless.  It only suggests there are too few data to be able to make such a demonstration.

Comment: @whuber This seems to ignore the very reasonable possibility that, in the population, the relationship has a sign opposite to whatever this regression found. Therefore, we would have high variance in our estimates, so the more parsimonious model that just uses the pooled mean to calculate the conditional mean would have lower MSE.

Comment: @Dave I'm trying to suggest that parsimony should not be the governing principle when there is information *in addition to the data* indicating what the model should be.  As an extreme example of this situation, if you were to collect a limited data set relating the times for dense objects to fall various distances and found that the p-value was 0.20, would you just as strongly recommend not applying Newton's laws and predicting the time as the average of the dataset?

Comment: @whuber Okay, point taken, though the relationship between age and speech recognition score does not strike me as nearly as obvious as it taking longer to fall 2 feet than 1 foot. I have emphatic prior knowledge for the falling exercise.

Comment: @Dave Precisely--which is why I have been tentative in my recommendations. There is no theory linking speech patterns with age that has the theoretical force of fundamental physical law.

Comment: Thank you @Dave and whuber for your inputs. So I can predict if the regression is not significant?. Thank you